# How do I get portal blocks?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

On the PS4, is it possible to get a nether portal block or an end portal block in my inventory to place wherever I want?

If so, how would that be done?

Comment: Portal frames or the portal itself?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ portal
```

for the nether and

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ end_portal
```

for the end, There's currently no way to get them into your inventory using only a PS4.